# Cracking hash knowing password length?

Tags: hash, passwords, brute-force, cracking, hashcat

I do know the password length is 24.

I also do know the search space: lower case, upper case and digits.

The combinations should be (26+26+10)^24 = 62^24, right?

I've tried with hashcat to set the charset and the mask

```
-1 ?l?u?d filename_to_crack ?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1?1
```

but it won't start because of an integer overflow error due to a huge keyspace; I guess the mask is too large!

Someone can suggest another solution? I was thinking maybe I could write a script that generate a file of random (24 length) strings and then using this to perform a dictionary attack.

Comment: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log_2(62%5E24) - that's the number of bits (142) you are trying to crack, higher than a 128 bit AES key... good luck!

Comment: With very good luck I could find the right random string within days! Otherwise I will become a vampire!

Comment: As Maarten suggested, you are not going to succeed by this method.  There are too many bits Unknown.

Comment: So even if you are lucky and they did wrong in using a fast hashing algorithm which can be brute-forced with 1Giga/sec, are you ready to wait for the expected 100'000'000'000'000'000'000'000'000 years?

Answer (score 0):

Your idea to pre-generate random strings to get around the integer overflow would work. It's not really a dictionary attack at that point, more a rainbow table approach. It's going to take up a lot of space too.

I might suggest trying a dictionary attack of 24 character passwords before generating your brute force list. Perhaps with the lists from https://crackstation.net/ or somewhere else, filtered for length 24, of course. If you want to get creative/more thorough, you could add rules to the passwords from these lists, like l33tspeak substitutions.

Comment: I already tried the two lists from crackstation, they both failed.
Il will try like you suggested to use these lists with adding some rules.
Which one do you suggest to try first between these two rules?
https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/blob/master/rules/leetspeak.rule
https://github.com/hashcat/hashcat/blob/master/rules/best64.rule

Comment: The first link.